# Backbone events not firing again

Tags: backbone.js

I read this one but since there was no answers and the question seems to irrelevant. I would like to ask it here again. I did exactly as the backbone documentation page instructs, but gained no results. Can someone help me point out what went wrong here?
The code as following:

```
App.View.Task = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template($("#taskTemplate").html()),

    event: {
        'click #edit': 'editTask'
    },

    editTask: function() {
        alert("test");
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
})
```

the index.html page looks like this:

`<script id="taskTemplate" type="text/template">
           <button class="edit">edit</button> <button>delete</button>
        </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring my typo when specify the element ID in the view, I found that the reason for Backbone not firing the event is because I load the script before that element.

Answer (score 2):

You have `#taskTemplate` in your JS, but `newe1` in your HTML.

Comment: and make this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes)) to this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

Comment: Possibly; while that is generally the common practice @petwho might have attributes which he doesn't want outputted in `toJSON` that he does want available to his templates.  There's nothing inherently wrong with using `attributes` to power templates.